# r search for a string based on keywords and check if date is between start and end date

Tags: r, string, date, filter, text-mining

I have a set of sentences,

`{ cat ate rat, rat was killed, cat killed the rat, rat killed by rat}`.

**First )** I want to search if the values in a column , col2, contains any of these sentences

**Second )** If there is a match, then I want to check if the date in Col3, is between the Start and End date in col4 and col5.

Here's a test dataset

```
Id      Col2                Col3        Col4        Col5
1       This cat            05-09-2001  04-10-2000  09-14-2001
2       This cat ate a rat  05-04-2011  05-01-2011  05-14-2011
3       Cat was killed      02-04-2015  02-01-2015  03-12-2015
4       Cat killed the rat  10-06-2014  09-20-2014  10-11-2014
5       Rat ran away        03-12-2008  04-12-2015  04-20-2015
```

This is the expected output

```
Id      Col2                Col3        Col4        Col5         Event
1       This cat            05-09-2001  04-10-2000  09-14-2001   No
2       Cat ate rat         05-04-2011  05-01-2011  05-14-2011   Yes
3       Cat died            02-04-2015  02-01-2015  03-12-2015   No
4       Cat killed the rat  10-06-2014  09-20-2014  10-11-2014   Yes
5       Rat ran away        03-12-2008  04-12-2015  04-20-2015   No
```

This is what id did so far. The code below is working. I get the results I want but this is very inefficient. It is very slow and takes a long time. Especially if my df contains 3million rows it will take me 10 days to finish running this code. Any advise on an efficient way to solve this problem is much appreciated.

keywords  <- c("cat ate rat", "rat was killed", "cat killed the rat", "rat killed by rat")

```
for (i in 1:NROW(Df)) {

         if( NROW(Df[grep(paste0(keywords, collapse = "|"), Df$Col2[i]),]) > 0) {

             if ( (Df$Col3[i] > Df$Col4[i]) & (Df$Col3[i] < Df$Col5[i]) ){
               Df$Event <- "Yes"
             } else {
               Df$Event <- "No"
             }


         }
        print(i)
      }
```

Comment: Please use `dput()` (see the R tag description)

Comment: Plus I would add that the test dataset and the expected output do not match. Why has Col2 changed ?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to test three conditions.

- `Col3` >= `Col4`
- `Col3` <= `Col5`
- `Col2` present in keywords

Use vectorized functions such as `ifelse` or `%in%` to speed up your code.

```
mydf <- structure(list(Id = 1:5, Col2 = c("This cat", "This cat ate a rat", 
"Cat was killed", "Cat killed the rat", "Rat ran away"), Col3 = structure(c(11451, 
15098, 16470, 16349, 13950), class = "Date"), Col4 = structure(c(11057, 
15095, 16467, 16333, 16537), class = "Date"), Col5 = structure(c(11579, 
15108, 16506, 16354, 16545), class = "Date")), .Names = c("Id", 
"Col2", "Col3", "Col4", "Col5"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")

keywords <- c("cat ate rat", "rat was killed", "cat killed the rat", "rat killed by rat")

mydf$event <- ifelse((mydf$Col3 >= mydf$Col4) & (mydf$Col3 <= mydf$Col5) 
                      & mydf$Col2 %in% keywords, "Yes", "No")
```

Note that this version is case sensitive. You might be interested by functions such as `tolower`.

```
mydf$event <- ifelse((mydf$Col3 >= mydf$Col4) & (mydf$Col3 <= mydf$Col5) 
                     & tolower(mydf$Col2) %in% keywords, "Yes", "No")
```

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**

```
df$Event <- sapply(tolower(df$Col2), function(el) el %in% sentences)
```

does what you want in the for loop.

In R, you have to avoid for loops and try to use **`apply`-family** functions.
**`tolower`** makes the content of df$Col2 lower case.
To every element of this column vector, the defined function **`function(el) el %in% sentences`** is **applied** (it asks whether each of the element is part of the `sentences` character vector, and the boolean result is collected first to a list, but then, it tries to  **s**implify the collected results further to a vector (**`sapply`**).

**Full working code version:**

**Data read-in and preparation**

```
sentences <- unlist(strsplit("cat ate rat, rat was killed, cat killed the rat, rat killed by rat",", "))
```

just to change your given text to a data frame

```
txt2df <- function(dfstr) {
  lines <- unlist(strsplit(txt, "\n"))
  l <- unlist(lapply(lines,strsplit, "\ {2, }"), recursive = FALSE)
  df <- as.data.frame(Reduce(rbind, l[2:length(l)]), row.names = FALSE)
  colnames(df) <- l[[1]]
  df
}
```

apply the function to the multiline string to obtain a data.frame:

```
df <- txt2df("Id      Col2                Col3        Col4        Col5
1       This cat            05-09-2001  04-10-2000  09-14-2001
2       This cat ate a rat  05-04-2011  05-01-2011  05-14-2011
3       Cat was killed      02-04-2015  02-01-2015  03-12-2015
4       Cat killed the rat  10-06-2014  09-20-2014  10-11-2014
5       Rat ran away        03-12-2008  04-12-2015  04-20-2015")


df

  Id               Col2       Col3       Col4       Col5
1  1           This cat 05-09-2001 04-10-2000 09-14-2001
2  2 This cat ate a rat 05-04-2011 05-01-2011 05-14-2011
3  3     Cat was killed 02-04-2015 02-01-2015 03-12-2015
4  4 Cat killed the rat 10-06-2014 09-20-2014 10-11-2014
5  5       Rat ran away 03-12-2008 04-12-2015 04-20-2015
```

**Lookup function**

lookup if lower case of df$Col2 values are any one of the sentences:

```
df$Event <- sapply(tolower(df$Col2), function(el) el %in% sentences)
```

**Result**

```
df

  Id               Col2       Col3       Col4       Col5 Event
1  1           This cat 05-09-2001 04-10-2000 09-14-2001 FALSE
2  2 This cat ate a rat 05-04-2011 05-01-2011 05-14-2011 FALSE
3  3     Cat was killed 02-04-2015 02-01-2015 03-12-2015 FALSE
4  4 Cat killed the rat 10-06-2014 09-20-2014 10-11-2014  TRUE
5  5       Rat ran away 03-12-2008 04-12-2015 04-20-2015 FALSE
```